# outputing lambda expression

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda

I'm having trouble in outputting the result because of the parameter Map in the Interface IArea

```
public class Lambda {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double x=10,y=8,pi=3.14159265359,radius=7;
        IArea triangle = (Map<ShapeProperties, Double> props) -> {
        props.put(ShapeProperties.base, x);
        props.put(ShapeProperties.height, y); 
        return (props.get(ShapeProperties.base) * 
        props.get(ShapeProperties.height) / 2);
        };

    IArea rectangle = (Map<ShapeProperties, Double> props) -> {
        props.put(ShapeProperties.width, x);
        props.put(ShapeProperties.length, y); 
        return (props.get(ShapeProperties.base) * 
        props.get(ShapeProperties.height));
        };

    IArea circle = (Map<ShapeProperties, Double> props) -> {
        props.put(ShapeProperties.radius, radius);
        return (pi*Math.pow(props.get(ShapeProperties.radius),2));
        };

  //this is the part where the error occurs.
    System.out.println(triangle.getArea(Map<ShapeProperties, Double> 
    props));
}   
}
```

could somebody please guide me on how should I approach the outputting part of this exercise? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to pass an argument in a method invocation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Yes as I have no Idea how to pass the Map<ShapeProperties, Double> 
    props in the System.out.println(triangle.getArea(Map<ShapeProperties, Double> 
    props)); when I was able to pass it to the lamba expression part .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
System.out.println(triangle.getArea(new HashMap<>()));
```

The point is that you need of pass a Map Object to triangle.getArea()